# How to pixelate photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, pixelation

How can I digitize or pixelate clay figures like Mason Lindroth does? https://masonlindroth.tumblr.com
Can it be done with photoshop? Im looking to do it only in black and white. Thank you for your help :)[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1bit MacPaint style Dithering](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87612/1bit-macpaint-style-dithering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

This is my way, non destrutive.

Create two adjustment Layes above your picture.

The first layer is a pattern fill, choosing the pattern. Mine is a stochastic one. Change the mode to Overlay.

The second layer is a threshold to make everything black and white.

Now just change the layer with the image to see the effect working.

See the image below:

[image]